# CSS navigation problem

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been trying to add another button to my navigation bar at http://hawaiiislandpreservationsociety.org/ ,but the layout messes up.  What do I need to tweak to get it inline with the rest of the buttons?

Much Appreciated,
Azeem

Answer (score 1):

```
#header ul
```

change the width to 802px;

(then download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/))

Answer (score 1):

adding 2px (making it 802px) to the #header ul makes it display correctly for me in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the problem that "Blog" ends up on its own line? It seems like #go_learn has a padding defined which, combined with the width definition of 200px, ends up making the element actually 202px wide.